# Material UI DataGrid Sorting Dates Not Working as Expected

Tags: javascript, sorting, material-ui

I am using Material UI DataGrid and one of my columns contains dates. The Material UI [documentation](https://mui.com/components/data-grid/sorting/) says to set the type to "date" in the column array, which I have done:

```
{
field: "submittedAt",
headerName: "Submitted",
minWidth: 150,
flex: 2,
type: "date",
headerClassName: "tableHeader",
cellClassName: "hoverPointer"
}
```

I am then converting my timestamp to MM/dd/yyyy format using Luxon

```
if (r.data().submittedAt) {
      const d = DateTime.fromMillis(r.data().submittedAt.toMillis());
      requestedDate = d.toFormat('MM/dd/yyyy')
    }
```

and then using `requestedDate` to set the value of the cell in the column. When I sort the data, the column is still sorting by a string comparator instead of by date:

[image]

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, and I can't seem to find much support in the documentation or in previous posts. I know I could set the date to yyyy/MM/dd so the string comparator works, but I don't want that format rendered for readability purposes. I also need the column to be dynamically sortable by the user, so server-side sorting won't help me out either. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 3):

What I did:

- in the data / the back end response, return an ISO timestamp that the DataGrid understands already (e.g. "2022-09-12T10:01:08+0200")
- just change the way that timestamp is displayed to the user.

This way, the adjustments that you need to make are minimal (just the rendering code)

```
    const dateFormattingOptions: Intl.DateTimeFormatOptions = {
        year: 'numeric',
        month: '2-digit',
        day: '2-digit',
        hour: '2-digit',
        minute: '2-digit',
        second: '2-digit'
    };

    function renderDate(checkTimeAndDate: any) {
        if (!checkTimeAndDate) {
            return '';
        }
        return new Date(checkTimeAndDate).toLocaleDateString(
            'de-DE',
            dateFormattingOptions
        );
    }
```

```
    const columns: GridColDef[] = [
        // ...
        {
            field: 'myTimeAndDateField',
            headerName: 'My Time and Date',
            width: 250,
            type: 'dateTime',
            renderCell: (params: GridRenderCellParams<MyDataTypeWithADateField>) =>
                renderDate(params.row.myTimeAndDateField)
        },
        // ...
    ];
```

```
    return (<DataGrid
        rows={myData}
        columns={columns}
        // ...
    />);
```

Testing:

```
test('the data table renders timestamps, formatted for Germany', async () => {
    // ...
    render(<MyComponent />);

    expect(findDataFieldValue('myTimeAndDateField')).toBe('12.09.2022, 10:01:08');
});


function findDataFieldValue(dataField: string): string | null | undefined {
    // material UI makes this into a div - I need to get conceptual table cell instead
    const element: HTMLElement | null = document.querySelector<HTMLElement>(
        "div[role='cell'][data-field='" + dataField + "']"
    );
    return element?.textContent;
}
```

Test data:

```
export const testData: MyDataTypeWithADateField = {
    // ...
    myTimeAndDateField: '2022-09-12T10:01:08+0200',
    // ...
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Render columns you can define like this.

```
const columns = [
    {
        field: 'date', headerName: 'Date', flex: 1, headerClassName: 'data-grid-header', type: 'date',
        renderCell: (params) =>
            renderDate(params.row?.date)
    }
];
```

Render function was used with date-fns in order to convert to format which i needed

```
//import
import {format} from 'date-fns'

    function renderDate(date) {
        if (!date) {
            return '';
        }
        return format(new Date(date), 'MM/dd/yyyy');
    }
```

Then a sortModel was used for date field sorting

```
<DataGrid
            className={'data-grid-data-row'}
            sx={{fontSize: '12px'}}
            rows={data}
            autoHeight {...data}
            columns={columns}
            pageSize={pageSize}
            rowsPerPageOptions={[10, 25, 50]}
            onCellClick={(params) => onRowClick(params)}
            initialState={{
                sorting: {
                    sortModel: [{field: 'date', sort: 'desc'}],
                }
            }}/>
```

This code segment accepts the timestamp and then sort them by date and render value according to the date time format we have defined in the function.

Answer (score -1):

i did resolved that problem ording the data of Datagrid in server and then i shorted the rows with sortComparator comparing the id's of each cell.

sortingOrder: ['desc', 'asc'],

sortComparator: (v1, v2, param1, param2) =>{

return param1.id - param2.id;

}

[an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8BMiA.png)